# Vue 2.7 + Pinia -> Import all stores from a folder for initialization

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I'm working on a Vue 2.7 + Pinia project and wanted to improve the store imports in application data loader utility, this is needed to register the stores before routing to the corresponding components.

There are a bunch of stores under `./src/stores/` directory e.g.:

- stores

  - applicationStore
  - step1Store
  - step2Store
    ...
    ...

Note: the app is a workflow application that users can save progress and resume
Hence, I need to initialize the stores when loading data from a pre-saved application.

Currently I'm importing each of the stores manually, so every time a new store is created I have to add an import here.

```
import { useStep1Store } from '../stores/step1Store.js'
import { useStep2Store } from '../stores/step2Store.js'

const useStep1Store = useStep1Store();
const useStep2Store = useStep2Store();
```

Can I do a bulk import and initialize the Pinia stores? Similar to how it's possible to do in Vuex
Something like:

```
import stores from '../stores'
```

I have tried using a simple FS reader and register stores, but it did not work